# How do you make the Page update after editing innerhtml in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a paragraph in HTML with id "headingram", I use JavaScript innerhtml to update the contents of the paragraph to "hello" , my code then prints the new value in the console.

So far, I can tell that the value is being updated as it is showing in the console however the actual web page does not refresh to show the new value, please find a snippet of the HTML and the JavaScript attached.

```
<div class="note-heading-indicate">
<h2><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Latest Notes</h2>
<p id="headingram">You have 10 new message.</p>
```

```
function HeadingChanger(){
    let HeadingTitle = document.getElementById('headingram').innerHTML ="hello";
    console.log(HeadingTitle);
}
```

Comment: Do you have more than one element with same ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my best guess, I think your code is somehow not calling the function properly. call it like this..

here is your code snippet which works like you need it.

```js
// call the function here..    
HeadingChanger()

function HeadingChanger(){
    let HeadingTitle = document.getElementById('headingram').innerHTML ="hello";
    console.log(HeadingTitle);
}
```

```html
<div class="note-heading-indicate">
    <h2><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Latest Notes</h2>
    <p id="headingram">You have 10 new message.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript `innerHTML` changes content in webPage but doesn't reload webpage.

In your case, the content in webpage should update without page refresh. Your code seems working.

See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-tree-hhmco?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I dont think the page refresh is an issue!